# Objective-C: Create UITextViews and UIImageViews from HTML string

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, json, uiimageview

So I am fairly new to working with iOS applications and I am currently working on an application which pulls data from a website using `NSURLSessionDataTask`, parses the JSON response (HTML), and then populates a view with data from the response.

Currently, I am stuck trying to find a solution to correctly parsing my current HTML string (of type `__NSCFString/NSString`) from the JSON response, and putting the text into one or more `UITextViews` and images into one or more `UIImageViews` within the main `ViewController`.

It has previously been suggested to [simply use a `UIWebView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900698/how-to-process-json-deliverd-html-text-into-formatted-uitextview) to display everything or to [use an outside library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158145/objective-c-how-to-display-html-img-tags-as-images-in-ios-without-uiwebview?rq=1) to do some of the converting, however I am curious if there are any methods by which I could parse the HTML and extract all relevant text or images and throw them into an array for later use. I would very much prefer to keep all of this native and not use outside libraries unless absolutely necessary.

I have also seen some use of the `NSAttributedString` class for parsing HTML from a JSON response, but am unsure if this is even relevant to what I am trying to do here. Any help/suggestions/thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: I do not understand your question. What exactly is the problem with setting a string into UITextView?

Comment: @rocky My current string is a bunch of HTML pulled directly from the website. Therefore, setting this string to the text of a UITextView will display a bunch of HTML to the user - not ideal.

Comment: A simple google will lead you to a bunch of hits on how to parse HTML. Here's the first hit. http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Comment: @rocky as previously mentioned I am looking for a native solution to extracting the text and photos. Just about everything I have found, including your link, rely on outside libraries. For the time being I am working with `NSAttributedString`, however it's proving difficult to work with and not grabbing all of the necessary images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native NSXMLParser class. Checkout the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/index.html).

Within your custom parsing class. You can generate NSAttributedString and store into array based on custom logic. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172669/how-can-i-parse-this-xml-using-nsxmlparser-in-ios) should help.

Comment: I don't think this is a solution I can use, as I am trying to parse HTML not XML and it looks like [`NSXMLParser` doesn't work with regular HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105972/can-nsxmlparser-be-use-to-parse-html?lq=1)